# Android Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle

I have developed several applications with Android Studio 1.5. A few days ago, I made a new application and I started getting this error during the Gradle builds:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\PATH\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried cleaning my project and then rebuilding, but this didn't do anything. I later found out that none of my previously working projects compiled anymore. I got the same error for them all. I have since tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, but every time I run this specific application, none of my projects work any longer. I don't know if it is something I did wrong with the application that first caused this error, but all of my projects compile this way now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add any custom exec type tasks to this app?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: use ./gradlew assemble --info to get more info